# In a Kivy form, how to add a new button dinamically to RecycleView using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, kivy

I have a Kivy form with one Recycleview. I would dinamically add a button to my Recycleview, by clicking a simple Button.
My Python3 script:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data=[]
class app(App):
    rv=RV()
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('lab.kv')
    def add_to_rv(self):
        self.rv.data.append('ok')
        # which command i should use to show new button in recycleview with new data?
app().run()
```

My kv file:

```
BoxLayout:
    RV:
        id:rv
        viewclass:'Button'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text:'ADD TO RV'
        on_press:app.add_to_rv()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add_to_rv()` method is adding to the data of `self.rv`. But `self.rv` is defined in the statement:

```
rv=RV()
```

which creates a new instance of `RV`. However, that instance of `RV` is not used in your GUI. The instance of `RV` that is displayed in your GUI is built by the line of code:

```
return Builder.load_file('lab.kv')
```

And those two instances are not related. The fix is to access the correct instance of `RV` in your `add_to_rv()` method like this:

```
def add_to_rv(self):
    self.root.ids.rv.data.append({'text': 'ok'})
```

Also, note that the `data` is a list of dictionaries. And you can eliminate the `rv=RV()` line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! of course it did not work...